# Table not found in subquery using Microsoft Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery, ms-access-2010

I'm trying to use subqueries in Microsoft Access 2010. Here is the table "Table1":

```
ID  data
--------
1   abc
2   def
```

There are two possible usage of subqueries:

```
SELECT ID
FROM (SELECT ID FROM Table1) AS tmp 
WHERE tmp.ID > 1
```

It works, and gives the correct result ID = 2. However,

```
SELECT ID
FROM (SELECT ID FROM Table1) AS tmp 
WHERE EXIST (SELECT ID FROM tmp WHERE ID > 1)
```

Gives the following error:

> The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the input table or query 'tmp'. Make sure it exists and that its name is spelled correctly.

It's not a good example of using subqueries, but I need to reference the results of a subquery in another subquery in more complicated cases, like:

```
SELECT Temp.rating
FROM (
    SELECT S.rating, AVG(S.age) AS avgage
    FROM Sailors S
    GROUP BY S.rating) AS Temp
WHERE  Temp.avgage = (
    SELECT MIN(Temp.avgage) 
    FROM Temp)
```

What is the cause of such errors and how to solve it?

Comment: My answer is an effort to correct some misconceptions that you have here.  I'm not sure if it answers your question directly.  Have you shown your specific query and the exact errors that you are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are much simpler ways to do what you are suggesting.

For example your second query can be refactored like this:

```
Select
  top 1 s.rating, avg(s.age) as avgage
from
  sailors s
group by s.rating
order by avg(s.age)
```

This gives you the minimum average age of the sailors grouped by their rating.

If you must use a subselect try:

```
SELECT rating, min(avgage)
FROM (
    SELECT S.rating, AVG(S.age) AS avgage
    FROM Sailors S
    GROUP BY S.rating) AS Temp
```

In the first section of your answer you give this query:

```
SELECT ID
FROM (SELECT ID FROM Table1) AS tmp 
WHERE EXIST (SELECT ID FROM tmp WHERE ID > 1)
```

This throws a syntax error because the tmp is *out of scope* in the exists.

I think you mean to do something like this, though I'm not sure it makes sense:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Table1 AS tmp 
WHERE EXIST (SELECT 
               1 
             FROM 
               Table1 tmp2 
              WHERE tmp.Id = tmp2.ID 
              and tmp2.Id > 1)
```

Notice that the self join between the two tables (`tmp` and `tmp2`) happens in the exists.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, why is the scope in the subquery different from the one in WHERE clause? Are there explicit rules?

Comment: @YenChiHsuan, there may be platforms that support that syntax, but Access isnt one of them.  Generally speaking (mysql as a notable exception) aliases cannot be used in other parts of a query.